# Why is includes in JavaScript case sensitive?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I recently stumbled upon a bug caused by `.includes()` method in javascript. I wanted to return the exact result in respect to case-insensitive but for some reason this does not works

```js
["Ford", "BMW", "Fiat"].includes("bmw");
//returns false
//expected result true
```

I then fixed my issue with the help of `.find()` like below:

```js
!!["Ford", "BMW", "Fiat"].find(el => el.toUpperCase() === "bmw".toUpperCase());
//returns true
```

Can someone help me understand why `includes` does not work in case-insensitive situations ?

Comment: You mean why it is case-**sensitive**?

Comment: @Cam but it doesn't look like a typo, more like the OP got really confused and thought case insensitive was case sensitive and vice versa (looking at the question body).

Comment: @code Yes I got confused during writing the question. Cam Thanks for fixing

Comment: @code I agree it's not a typo, but I think the edited version reflects better what the question meant to ask, which is "why is includes in JavaScript not ignoring case?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why *would* it work case-insensitively? Quoth [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

> The `includes()` method determines whether an array includes a certain value among its entries, returning true or false as appropriate.
> [...]
> Note: Technically speaking, includes() uses the `sameValueZero` algorithm to determine whether the given element is found.

`sameValueZero` is defined to be [`Object.is`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is) but with `+0` and `-0` being equal.

That being the case, we can try that out:

```
> Object.is("bmw", "BMW")
false
> Object.is("bmw", "bmw")
true
```

Comment: So, it's natural behavior of `includes`, right?

Comment: It's how it's defined to work, yes...